# Iterate over a dictionary based on sum of values in Python

Tags: python, while-loop

L1: List of indexes of missing values in the column number 2.

dctn: dictionary having month as key and number of missing values in each month as values.

I want to replace the values of the column until the sum of values is 0.

I tried using a loop

```
while (sum(dctn.values())!=0):
 for i in L1:
  for k, v in dctn.items():
   if ( (df.iloc[i,0].month==k) and (v==1) ) :
    ...
    v=v-1
   if ( (df.iloc[i,0].month==k) and (v==2) ):
    ...
    v=v-1
```

Infinite loop, doesn't show any result.

Comment: provide a sample of how `dctn` and `L1` looks like, it will make your question much more easy to solve. Also provide the corresponding expected output

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify a value like that. What you want is this

```
for k, v in dictn.items():
  if <condition>:
    ...
    dictn[k] -= 1
```

`items` gives a view object[1] meaning it gives you **values** reflecting what is in the dictionary but they are not pointers to the items. You should treat `v` as a snapshot of the value at the beginning of your loop.

[1] https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items